# How {% url %} works in Django?

Tags: django, url

in my django project I have template 'base.html'. On the bottom of it is a link to main page. Everything worked fine to some point. Now, when I run server I got that:

**No module named 'views'**

In template `..\my_project\basket\templates\basket\base.html`, error at line

```
<a href="{% url 'basket:index' %}">Main page</a>
```

When i change `"{% url 'basket:index' %}"` to `"\"` (that is what `{%url%}` previously generated) it works properly.

Here is how my direcory structure looks like:

```
my_project
   basket
      templates
         basket
            base.html
            index.html
      admin.py
      forms.py
      models.py
      urls.py
      views.py
  my_project
      settings.py
      urls.py
      views.py
  manage.py
```

And here is code of basket/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from basket import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

my_project/urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'', include('basket.urls', namespace="basket")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
)
```

Comment: You have an exception it  basket/urls.py file. Please provide full exception page text. 
Do you add 'basket' app to INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: I've changed it back to "{% url 'basket:index' %}" to copy exception page but now it generates "/" again so my site works properly. I had 'basket' in INSTALED_APPS. When I find out what was my problem I'll post it. Thx!